# Populate Properties from Database in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I would like to populate a property source from Database using `ApplicationStartingEvent`.

My approach is to perform sql queries and fetch the data from database tables. I need to access datasource to fetch the data from database. I do not require Entities or Repositories. I am planning to do raw sql queries.

How can I access Datasource in `ApplicationStartingEvent` of Spring Boot ?

I tried googling and found nothing.

Thanks in advance.